# How can i pass the Array obtained from "each" inside the "click" function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
$('.menu-colors_page > span').each(function () {
    var arr_color = [];
    arr_color.push($(this).attr('class'));

    $(this).click(function (arr_color) {
         console.log(arr_color);
    });
});
```

I tried like this but it doesn't work

Q: How to call arr_color inside click?
q: How can i pass parameter from "each" function to "click" function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
var arr_color = []; /* global variable */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-colors_page > span').each(function() {
    arr_color.push($(this).attr('class'));
  });  
  $('.menu-colors_page > span').click(function() {
      console.log(arr_color);
  });
});
```

```css
span{
  padding:2px;
  margin:1px; 
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-colors_page">
  <span class="red">span blue</span>
  <span class="green">span green</span>
  <span class="blue">span blue</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's working for me but its global variable.